# Merge two arrays and get the duplicates in a variable

Tags: swift

I have for example two arrays, how do I merge them together, but in the same time get the duplicates. Is there any way to that wihout looping through the whole merged array? My array will have lots of data in it so I don't want to load it slower.

For example:

```
let arrayone = ["1", "2" ,"3", "4"]
let arraytwo = ["1", "4", "5"]
```

How do I get in a variable for example: ["1", "4"]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [intersection(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1779150-intersection) operation of `Set`. You just need to convert the arrays to `Set` and convert the result back to `String` array.

```
let duplicates: [String] = Array(Set(arrayone).intersection(Set(arraytwo)))
```

Comment: Minor complement: there is a type mismatch. Need to convert to Array.                                                   let duplicates: [String] = Array(Set(arrayone).intersection(Set(arraytwo)))

Comment: Guys, thank you, that works perfect, I will accept the answer when I can!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the same order as in original array:

```
let duplicates = Set(arrayone).intersection(Set(arraytwo))
let orderedDuplicates = arraytwo.filter { duplicates.contains($0)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I sort it in a different way, but again, thanks for your time